# freetds locale.conf, date format

Tags: php, odbc, freetds

I'm using freetds and following [manual](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/locales.htm) I can set date format in `/etc/locale.conf`. From origin I didn't have it, so I created it manually. And now I'm getting such date format:

```
May 21 2013 05:30:39:000PM
```

I set `locales.conf` like this:

```
[default]
    date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[en_US]
    date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    language = us_english
#    charset = iso_1

[es_ES]
    date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    language = spanish
#    charset = iso_1

[pt_BR]
    date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    language = Portuguese
#    charset = iso_1

[it_IT]
    date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    language = Italiano
#    charset = iso_1
```

But seems like `freetds` doesn't look at this file while getting settings of locales. How can I make it work

Comment: Did you find the issue? I also have that situation: changing `/etc/locale.conf` on most servers worked but in my current case it doesn't.

Comment: @robbash Nope! Feels like a deer