# Reinstall/reconfigure php

Tags: php, web, installation

I need to change some configuration of my PHP (installed on Ubuntu). I installed it like this:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql php5-fpm php-pear php5-cgi php5-odbc php5-curl php5-sybase
```

Now I want to make it

```
--with-sybase-ct=/opt/freetds
```

How to achieve this in correct way?

**UPD** Is deleting and installing from scratch the one way?

Comment: You have an X/Y Problem. What is your end goal? What are you trying to achieve as the *final* result? (What functionality are you expecting that `--with-sybase-ct=/opt/freetds` should give you?)

Comment: @Piskvor I previously asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239203/freetds-locale-conf-date-format) that didn't get any answer. And I'm still unable to solve it. I checked `phpinfo` on a remote web-server where locales work fine and compared it with my `phpinfo` and `--with-sybase-ct=/opt/freetds` is the one difference between my and remote php config so I wanted to try maybe this will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use .configure flags with apt.

There is two ways:

- do not use apt and build php with proper .configure flags
- recompile package for your needs (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345183/configuration-options-while-apt-get-installing) for more details)

Comment: Thanks. But this is my trouble, I don't know where to start, should I remove my php and install it again compiling with prop config by myself?